# Django admin site privilege escalation

Tags: privilege-escalation, django

Last night, I read a PDF detailing a privilege escalation attack a researcher had performed on a Django admin site. I'm curious- was the unfortunate application susceptible to this attack due to a misconfiguration, or rather due to an inherent vulnerability in Django itself?

Here's the PDF.
https://seanmelia.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/django-privilege-escalation-e28093-zero-to-superuser.pdf

I'd also like to note that I'm new to Django and would appreciate knowing any other inherent vulnerabilities you know of.

Answer (score 1):

This was a programming error on the web dev's end. Not a Django vulnerability.

Django vulnerability lists can be found on the Offical CVE site:

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-10199/product_id-18211/Djangoproject-Django.html